# Is there any pattern to avoid a popup on page load?

Tags: interface, popup, workflow, wizard

I am working on a social media tool, and upon adding a new account it takes me to a new screen but before I can go and view the added account in the new screen I am supposed to set a few toggle? How do i do this without showing a popup?

Comment: You're going to have to give us more to work from here, I think. Can you provide some mockups of what you've got so far?

Comment: I don't think that'll be possible since its quite a long flow. However, Its somewhat like this:

Page 1>>Add an account(cta)>>Authorize(popup)>>Settings for that account(in the same popup)>>Page 2

In page 2 user can add more accounts and can also view and edit settings for already added accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set a cookie that checks if the user is already registered/logged.

Some basic pseudo code to better explain what I mean

```
if $new_user => $popup
else => $page2
```

Additionally, settings shouldn't be in that popup. If you use oauth or any other kind of authorization method, **leave the popup only for login purposes**, then have an user admin page with all the settings. Otherwise, how will the user get back to that popup again if s/he needs to make any adjustments?

Comment: There is an edit button to each added account on page 2 to get the popup back.

Comment: but you want to go to Page2 without showing the popup, so this solves your problem, not to mention it's a common UX pattern. Just check any social media site and you'll see what I mean